VS2022 Javascript Breakpoint will not currently be hit Unbound Breakpoint
I have an MVC 5 app. It has a .js file. I'm trying to log to the console for debugging purposes. I add a line with console.log("hi"), and I set a breakpoint on the line as follows:

When I hit F5, the breakpoint becomes hollow and the warning triangle appears on the breakpoint:

When I hover over the breakpoint it says "Th breakpoint will not currently be hit Unbound Breakpoint"
And then the dynamic window comes up and the console.log line disappears and the breakpoint moves to the next line:

If I go to the browser and open developer tools, console line doesn't exist
I have tried, the following:

toggling between release and debug modes
closing and reopening VS
tried using a different line of code (var x=1;)
Ran Clean Solution

Any ideas for what I can try?

May be caused by a debug configuration. Please try the following steps to resolve this issue:
1: Right-click the project in Solution Explorer, go to Properties/Build/General, and set "Debug Symbols" to "PDB file, portable across platforms."
2: If you have a multi-project solution, go to Solution > Properties.
Then change from "Single startup project" to "Multiple startup project".
3: Next to the "Debug/Release" dropdown list, there is another one with "Any CPU/Configuration Manager...". Click "Configuration Manager...", and you will see some of your projects might be in Release mode. Change all of them to Debug.
4: Please go to your solution folder and delete (or rename) the "obj" , "bin” and the hidden “.vs” folder, restart Visual Studio, and then rebuild your solution.
If this answer is not what you want, please provide a more detailed description of your requirements.

#2 was it - Thanks Cody!
